# How to create npm package that groups other packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have two npm packages say `foo-js` and `bar-js`, now I want to create `foo-bar-js` that will allow me to use both `bar-js` and `foo-js` in my project.

I created new package and added `foo-js` and `bar-js` as dependencies, but `npm pack` created package with only `package.json`. Should I include `index.js` that requires both packages? Is it good idea to create such groupping package, what do you think?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would want a 3rd package that simply groups other packages. Either way all three packages would be dependencies. By grouping them you lose the ability to `require('foo')`, instead you have to always `require('foo-bar')` even if you only need `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: The idea is that `foo-js` will be used with `bar-js` in 90% of cases, but I want to leave room for these that want only `foo-js` or only `bar-js`. So it may not be a good idea, I guess...

Comment: You could always group them using a .js inside your project instead of a separate module. I usually do this with my mongoose connector.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Peer Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies) and see if that would solve your problem.

Just have packages `foo` and `bar` reference each other.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` should be also usable independently of each other, it is just common case that they will be used both.

Comment: PeerDepencies says: "In some cases, you want to express the compatibility of your package with a host tool or library, while not necessarily doing a require of this host."   I'm not sure why this wouldn't be your exact situation.     Otherwise, I would just not relate them at all, and people will get used to using them together if that's what they like.

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the comments, I decided to abandon this groupping package idea.